# Oracle trigger probably issue with :new

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
create trigger Trigger_1
    Before INSERT
    on Adresse
    for each row
    declare
        pruefen int;
begin
    select COUNT(*) 
    into pruefen 
    from CITY 
    where city.NAME = :new.stadt 
    and CITY.PROVINCE = :new.provinz;
    if(pruefen = 0) then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Fehler');
    end if;
end;
```

Error:

> [2020-01-18 10:14:12] [72000][20000] ORA-20000: Fehler
>   [2020-01-18 10:14:12] ORA-06512: in "ZOGL1011.TRIGGER_1", Row 6
>   [2020-01-18 10:14:12] ORA-04088: error during execution of Trigger "ZOGL1011.TRIGGER_1"
>   [2020-01-18 10:14:12] Position: 12

I don't get the problem.. `:new.stadt` and `:new.provinz` are in red, but I can create the trigger.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: its an execution issue, if i insert something...

Comment: Is data types of the `:new.stadt` and `city.name` same? Also, Is data type of the `:new.provinz` and `city.province` same?

Comment: yes the datatyp of those are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [2020-01-18 10:14:12] [72000][20000] ORA-20000: Fehler

That is the error your trigger raises when there is no data in CITY which matches the record you're trying to insert into ADRESSE. In other words it is your trigger **working as designed**. So if this outcome surprises you you need to check the data you're using for both CITY and ADRESSE.

Just to prove it, [here is a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d509514472913826eb096d6cace865ac).

---

Incidentally, this seems like the sort of thing which is properly enforced through a foreign key. Using a trigger to enforce a relationship is wrong because:

1. It performs worse and doesn't scale.
2. It may fail in a multi-user environment.
3. It won't continue to enforce the relationship when DML is executed on the referenced table (CITY in your case).
4. In obfuscates the data model.
5. Using non-standard approaches confuses other developers who have to work with or maintain your code.

Maybe you have a poor data model which won't allow you to use a foreign key here? Perhaps CITY is missing a unique key of `(state, province)`.

Although probably this is just the assignment. It is the fate of triggers to be used in homework exercises in ways in which they should never be used in real life.